# Java Vector Api comparing two vectors

Tags: java, vector

Why using Java Vector API from Java 21 (incubator), I compare two vectors and copy result into array. It fauls with exception:
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 2`
There is no method: `v3.intoArray(result, i, mask);` that accept mask.
How to compare arrays using vector api and copy result to another array?

```
      int[] a1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
      int[] a2 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
      boolean[] result = new boolean[] {false, false, false, false, false};
        
      var species = IntVector.SPECIES_PREFERRED;
      for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i += species.length()) {
        var mask = species.indexInRange(i, a1.length);
        var v1 = IntVector.fromArray(species, a1, i, mask);
        var v2 = IntVector.fromArray(species, a2, i, mask);
        VectorMask<Integer> v3 = v1.eq(v2);
        v3.intoArray(result, i)
        // v3.intoArray(result, i, mask); - no method wtih mask ! here exception
      }
```

Comment: Do you mean [*JEP 448: Vector API (Sixth Incubator)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/448) being incubated in Java 21? If so, say so in your Question. Include a link.

Comment: Added information about Java version and Incubator.

Comment: I don't know anything about this `Vector` API, but what happens if you change `i += species.length()` to `i++`?

Comment: This is a problem that I want to compare two arrays using Vectors. But there is a problem of last vector, that was solved in different operations by allowing Mask. The mask is not here in the method.

Comment: Vector examples I've seen use a loop that ends `upperBound = SPECIES.loopBound(a1.length)` and performs normal iteration from that point for the remaining items which are not a multiple of `species.length()`. See the example in JEP mentioned by Basil Bourque

Comment: ...  or declare `boolean[] result` as next multiple of `species.length()`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a call `VectorMask<Integer>.intoArray(result, i, mask)` - I suggest you follow up with the mailing lists for Vector API development. As a result the final iteration is trying to copy values beyond the size of `result[]`.

You either can perform the final iterations in a loop, without mask:

```
private static boolean[] compareWithLoop(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    boolean[] result = new boolean[a1.length];
    int upperBound = SPECIES.loopBound(a1.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < upperBound; i += SPECIES.length()) {
        var v1 = IntVector.fromArray(SPECIES, a1, i);
        var v2 = IntVector.fromArray(SPECIES, a2, i);
        VectorMask<Integer> v3 = v1.eq(v2);
        v3.intoArray(result, i);
    }
    // Scalar loop for end:
    for (int i = upperBound; i < a1.length; i++) {
        result[i] = a1[i] == a2[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or entend `result` so it can hold a multiple of `species.length()` larger than `a1.length`. This will evaluate the results as `result` is large enough to handle the tail when `a1.length` isn't an exact multiple of `SPECIES.length()`:

```
private static boolean[] compareWithMask(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    boolean[] result = new boolean[a1.length+SPECIES.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i += SPECIES.length()) {
        var mask = SPECIES.indexInRange(i, a1.length);
        var v1 = IntVector.fromArray(SPECIES, a1, i, mask);
        var v2 = IntVector.fromArray(SPECIES, a2, i, mask);
        VectorMask<Integer> v3 = v1.eq(v2);
        v3.intoArray(result, i);
    }
    // You are only interested in result for the size of a1.length:
    return Arrays.copyOf(result, a1.length);
}
```

Note that species should be static final:

```
private static final VectorSpecies<Integer> SPECIES = IntVector.SPECIES_PREFERRED;
```

Test program for above:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] a1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] a2 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] a3 = new int[] {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(compareWithMask(a1, a2)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(compareWithLoop(a1, a2)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(compareWithMask(a1, a3)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(compareWithLoop(a1, a3)));
}
```

Should print:

```
[true, true, true, true, true]
[true, true, true, true, true]
[false, false, true, false, false]
[false, false, true, false, false]
```

Comment: It sounds like some kind of plan B. I am still searching for optimal solution.

Comment: It is vector operation. Does it matter a great deal if the final iteration, of what would normally be a great deal more than 2, produces more results than you use?